# PHP GD Not resampling image correctly (not scaling properly)

Tags: php, image, gd, image-resizing

I'm trying to resample images on the fly using GD.

Basically I'm trying to emulate the CSS's `background-size: cover;`

My class takes the path name of the file, then the `cover` method takes the dimensions of the element to cover.

First, here's the code:

```
<?php

class Image{
    
    public $filepath;
    public $width;
    public $height;
    public $mime;
    public $image;
    public $landscape;
    public $imageFunct;
    public $compression;
    
    public function __construct($fn){
        
        // The path to the /img directory
        $ImgPath = realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))."/img";
        
        // Find the actual path, look in all relevant directories
        $fp = $ImgPath."/$fn";
        if(!file_exists($fp)) $fp = $ImgPath."/backgrounds/$fn";
        if(!file_exists($fp)) throw new Exception("Image source file does not exist: $fp"); 
        
        $this->filepath = $fp;
        $data = getimagesize($fp);
        $this->width = $data[0];
        $this->height = $data[1];
        $this->landscape = $this->width > $this->height;
        $this->mime = $data['mime'];
        switch($this->mime){
            case("image/png"):
                $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->filepath);
                $this->imageFunct = 'imagepng';
                $this->compression = 9;
                break;
            case('image/jpeg'):
            case('image/pjpeg'):
            case('image/x-jps'):
                $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->filepath);
                $this->imageFunct = 'imagejpeg';
                $this->compression = 100;
                break;
            case('image/gif'):
                $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($this->filepath);
                $this->imageFunct = 'imagegif';
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid image type. Only excepts PNG, JPG, and GIF. You entered a {$this->mime} type image.");
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * scales the image to cover the dimensions provided
     * @param type $width
     * @param type $height
     * @param type $output_mimetype (defaults to the original image's mimtype)
     */
    public function cover($width, $height, $output_mimetype=''){
        
        $imgRatio = $this->height/$this->width;
        $canvasRatio = $height/$width;
        
        if ($canvasRatio > $imgRatio){
            $finalHeight = $height;
            $scale = $finalHeight / $this->height;
            $finalWidth = $this->width * $scale;
        }else{
            $finalWidth = $width;
            $scale = $finalWidth / $this->width;
            $finalHeight = $this->height * $scale;
        }
        
        // Resize the image
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($finalWidth, $finalHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $finalWidth, $finalHeight, $this->height, $this->height);
        
        // Get output details
        switch(strtoupper($output_mimetype)){
            case('JPG'):
            case('JPEG'):
                $mimetype = 'image/jpeg';
                $funct = 'imagejpeg';
                $compression = 100;
                break;
            case('PNG'):
                $mimetype = 'image/png';
                $funct = 'imagepng';
                $compression = 9;
                break;
            case('GIF'):
                $mimetype = 'image/gif';
                $funct = 'imagegif';
                $compression = null;
                break;
            default:
                $mimetype = $this->mime;
                $funct = $this->imageFunct;
                $compression = $this->compression;
        }
        
        // Output and clear memory
        header('Content-Type: '.$mimetype);
        
        // Get and call the image creation 
        // function with the correct compression/quality
        if(!empty($compression)) 
            $funct($thumb, null, $compression);
        else 
            $funct($thumb, null);
        
        imagedestroy($thumb);
    }
    
}
```

Here's the original source image
[image: Original Image]

After calling `$img->cover(1669, 556)`, I get an image with the correct proportions, but instead of stretching the original image to fit the width, it just fills the space to the left with black. Here's the output:

[image: Output image]

How can I get the image to stretch to fill the black space... ?

BTW, landscape images seem to work just fine with the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm just retarded, that's all..

```
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $finalWidth, $finalHeight, $this->height, $this->height);
```

Probably shouldn't use the height as the width..